# python assignment and logical eval one-liner

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to execute the following *pseudo* code concept:

```
if easy_to_eval_var or (r = heavy_func()):
    .
    .
    .
    do_something_with_heavy_func_output(r)
```

Python cannot evaluate a **statement** (unlike C), and therefor such syntax will not work.
Is there a one-liner expression that is:

1. Readable
2. Will not evaluate `heavy_func()` unless needed
3. Save the result to variable (without an additional call to `heavy_func()`)

Comment: What would `r` be in your code if `easy_to_eval_var` is truthy? It seems like you may want `r = easy_to_eval or heavy_func(); if r: ...`

Comment: I broke the code into two statements:
`r = None if easy_to_eval_var else heavy_func()
if easy_to_eval_var or r:
    do_something_with_heavy_func_output(r)`